# How to mock/fake HTML code of a component instance in a spec.ts file ( ng test )

Tags: angular, typescript, mocking

My spec.ts file :

```
describe('CenterPricesComponent', () => {

    let component: CenterPricesComponent;
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<CenterPricesComponent>;
    let service: MockPriceRulesService;
    let centersService: MockCentersService;

    beforeEach(async(() => {
        service = new MockPriceRulesService(null);
        centersService = new MockCentersService(null);
        TestBed.overrideProvider(PriceRulesService, { useValue: service });
        TestBed.overrideProvider(CentersService, { useValue: centersService});
        TestBed.configureTestingModule(testBed).compileComponents();

        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(CenterPricesComponent);
        fixture.detectChanges();
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
    }));
.
.
.
```

Here I am mocking two services used in the component with fakes services that I created before. I would like to know if it is possible to do that with the HTML template of this componentInstance `component`.

EDIT :

```
constructor(
    private priceruleService: PriceRulesService,
    private windowService: NbWindowService,
    private centerService: CentersService,
    private route: ActivatedRoute
  ) { }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to not use the HTML, then simply do not use the test bed, which is basically made to use it.

```
let component: CenterPricesComponent = new CenterPricesComponent(
  // Your mocked dependencies
);
```

#### EDIT

In case I haven't been clear enoug you need to **MOCK IT**.

```
let component: CenterPricesComponent = new CenterPricesComponent(
  // Your activated route
  { snapshot: { paramMap : { get: () => '', } } } as any
);
```

Comment: I edited my post, i added the constructor of my component. As you can see there is a `ActivatedRoute`. If i create simply my component like this ( new ... ), my ActivatedRoute variable will be undefined. The thing is that in my component's functions, I do `this.route.snapshot`, so I got this error `Cannot read property 'snapshot' of undefined`

Comment: I also wasn't clear enough : that's precisly what I do in my component's functions : `    const id = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');`, now the error is `Cannot read property 'get' of undefined
`

Comment: @sowebull excuse me if it's offensive, but do you even know what mocking means ? Have you read the Angular documentation about testing ?

Comment: it's not offensive, but how i am supposed to mock an `ActivatedRoute` ?

Comment: @sowebull sorry, I'm taking gloves now, this site is filled with snowflakes :) See my new edit : you have to provide all used methods. If you don't, they will always throw errors.